# 9 week old started fussing during evening nursing

Tags: newborn, breastfeeding, feeding

Two days ago our 9 - almost 10 - week old breastfeeding daughter started fussing during evening nursing. Yesterday it was better, there was little screaming (though there was some), but today we're back to really loud and intensive fussing. It's almost crying. And she seems really angry.

For a few minutes she feeds OK - then fusses - then, sometimes, feeds well for some more time. It does not seem to be connected to whether the milk is actually flowing from the breast.

There's nothing that we can think of that had changed in us, our home, the way we feed her or hold her. What could be the reason of her fussiness?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out that she was in the middle of a growth spurt and it (with a bit of overtiredness, she didn't nap too well around that time) seems to have been the cause.

Three days later she mastered grabbing and holding toys and since the feeding problem has gone away on its own.

Still, thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 1):

When my son behaved in the same way, it turned out to be a candida infection in his mouth. This is very common in babies. I'm sure other people will have plenty of other ideas, but I just wanted to mention this possibility.

Comment: The problem is that she only fusses during one single feeding - the evening one, just before sleep. All other nursings cause no fussing at all. And we have checked her mouth for any signs of infection and weren't able to see anything out of the oridinary.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried giving her some ***gripe water***  ? It is an excellent old remedy for colic, better known as wind.
Sometimes babies have to be patted on the back for over half an hour ,gently to bring up wind because if it doesn't all come up the colic sits like a bubble in their belly and causes pain.

Some babies are blessed with little or none whilst others are different.

Believe me it doesn't affect how they grow.
Do you have Baby Health Clinics where you live ? If so ask the nurse when you take your daughter for a check up...She would be able to advise other solutions.

One or two teaspoons of Gripe Water over a 24 hour period is usually sufficient to fix the problem currently.

As a extra measure you may find that you have to give her some every second night to help her expel the wind. It is not a medicine that has to be bought on a script. It is available over the counter from most pharmacies.